# How to build a multipage form using Freeform?

Tags: form, plugin-freeform, freeform

I've been trying to search for some instructions on how to build a multipage form using Freeform in Craft CMS.

The official documentation is very light on the subject; https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/multi-page-forms/ and there seems to be a general lack of information on the subject elsewhere.

Can anyone explain the steps I need to take in order to create a multipage form?

The form I'm creating is 2 pages in total. I need it to validate page 1 when the 'Next' button on page 1 is clicked, and then validate page 2 and submit the entire form when the 'Submit' button on page 2 is clicked.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction to some information on the subject?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the templates that are provided in the docs over [here](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/formatting-template-examples/) are a pretty good place to start. You can change the markup, but you need the `javascript:;` tag in the `a href=`to get the multi-steps working.

Like any other form, I would suggest that you use some front-end validation. There are some nice libraries out there that get you up and running pretty quickly.

Are there any specifics you're struggling with?